# How to call MDIParent from windows form?

Tags: vb.net, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I have an MDI form called "MDIParent1", MDI child form "MDIChild1" and I have a windows form called "FrmTest".

Now there is a button called "btnTest" in "MDIChild1" form and here is the click event.

```
Dim V As New FrmTest
    V.MdiParent = MDIParent1
    V.Show()
```

But It couldn't load the "frmTest" form. Is there any another way to do so?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
    Dim V As New FrmTest
    V.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
    V.Show()
```

The above assumes that `MDIChild1.MdiParent` is already set to `MDIParent1`

You could also do this :

```
    Dim V As New FrmTest
    V.MdiParent = Application.OpenForms("MDIParent1")
    V.Show()
```

To close other forms, iterate through `MdiChildren` collection :

```
    Dim MyMdiForm as Form = Application.OpenForms("MDIParent1")

    For Each Frm As Form In MyMdiForm.MdiChildren  

          If Frm IsNot V Then

                Frm.Close()

          End If

     Next
```

Comment: FrmTest is not MDIParent. MDIParent1 is my MDIParent.

Comment: @AzharMansuri if `MDIChild1.MdiParent` is set to `MDIParent1` then the above will work.

Comment: Thanks it is working fine. But how can I close other Child forms?